# closing jquery colorbox before load breaks jquery,

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, colorbox

I am using jquery [colobox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) to show the popup in my asp.net mvc(C#) application.

Following is the line to call colorbox:

```
$.fn.colorbox({ href: '/User/Detail', width: "1200px", height: "560px", title: "User Detail", overlayClose: false });
```

UPDATE(using the below with the latest version):

```
$.colorbox({ href: '/User/Detail', width: "1200px", height: "560px", title: "User Detail", overlayClose: false });
```

When i click the close button of colorbox, before it opens, it breaks everything including jquery.

I am showing the user details (Personal, Billing,...) in jquery tabs in the popup which is opened using colorbox. When i click a link to open the colorbox (User details) and when i click the close button, before it loads (when still showing loader), the next time when i click the same link its not showing the tabs and all the events (like click binded through jquery) are broken.

Any idea on this?

Comment: i can barely see the original content in the background of popup opened second time. The popup opened second time shows as such when the tabs are not initialised, I have also looked using firebug, but it shows no error.

Comment: previusly i have been using v1.3.6. I have updated the colorbox to the latest v1.3.9 also. but still the same issue

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but in a pinch you could hide the close button until it's loaded..

Comment: thats a good idea i can make now temporarily, but i am curious why its happening so

Comment: Hiding the close button won't work, because the user can click outside the box to close it.

Comment: @fudgey, we can stop that by using (escKey and overlayClose) like:

$.colorbox({ href: '/User/Detail', width: "1200px", height: "560px", title: "User Detail", overlayClose: false, escKey: false, onLoad: function() { $('#cboxClose').hide() }, onComplete: function() { $('#cboxClose').show() } });

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an iframe?... this is from the documentation:

> **ColorBox broken or displaying incorrectly when loading documents:**
>
> Often this is due to not using an
>   iframe when an iframe would be
>   required. The default method, ajax, is
>   only for elements that can exist
>   within a  element.
>
> If you are loading a complete HTML
>   document with , , and
>    elements, then using an iframe
>   is required. While nesting these
>   elements may appear to display
>   correctly in some browsers, it is
>   still invalid HTML and should not be
>   depended on. Remember to set the width
>   and height values for ColorBox when
>   using an iframe, it has no way of
>   knowing the dimensions of elements
>   that exist within the iframe.
>
> ColorBox leverages jQuery's load
>   method for handling ajax. If you are
>   loading a document from the same
>   domain as your current document, you
>   can use a selector pull out just the
>   portion of the document that is
>   needed. Example:
>
> ```
> $('#example').colorbox({href:"document.html div#content"});
> ```

Comment: no. i am not using iframe,. just opening the popup using:

$.colorbox({ href: '/User/Detail', width: "1200px", height: "560px", title: "User Detail", overlayClose: false, escKey: false, onLoad: function() { $('#cboxClose').hide() }, onComplete: function() { $('#cboxClose').show() } });

Comment: i made a temporary fix only as @fosco said.